# What does it mean to instantiate a class?

Tags: java

This is the criteria:

- The nsLookup class is instantiated with a string that deﬁnes the host to be
  queried.
- The constructor instantiates the InetAddress object using this string.
- A method is designed to resolve the lookup query. The query can return multiple
  IP addresses if they exist. These should be returned to the GUI as an array of
  String objects for display.

This is the code:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class NsLookup {

  private InetAddress inet = null;

  public void resolve(String host) {
    try {
      inet = InetAddress.getByName(host);

      System.out.println("Host name : " + inet.getHostName());
      System.out.println("IP Address: " + inet.getHostAddress());
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NsLookup lookup = new NsLookup();
    lookup.resolve(args[0]);
  }
}
```

Please help me with examples if possible?

Comment: "instantiate" means "create a new instance".

Comment: See [first result](https://www.google.com/search?q=instantiate+a+class). See also the [official tutorial on object creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Answer (score 9):

To instantiate something is to create an object of that type.  You are doing that here:

```
NsLookup lookup = new NsLookup();
```

and here:

```
inet = InetAddress.getByName(host);
```

Comment: +1 Total nitpick: There is one possible case, looking at the source, where `InetAddress.getByName()` might *not* instantiate an `InetAddress`, and that is if `host` is `null` or an empty string, in which case it may return a global `InetAddress` representing the loopback address.

Comment: Small addition: always distinguish between object (such as class) instantiation and variable initialisation. Those two are different.